# C# Is it possible to call a method from a property within a class?

Tags: c#, class, methods, properties

So I'm pretty new to programming, and I try to learn new things by trying a lot of things. But at the moment I got stuck on something...

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is to be able to use the following line of code:
`Url.QueryStringParser.HasParam("");` The Url is the class, `QueryStringParser` a property within the Url class and the `HasParam` is a method within the `QueryStringParser` class.
And it work, expect for the fact that I get a `NullReferenceException` on the `QueryStringParser` propperty. And I can't figure out why this happens...

This is the `Url` class.

```
public class Url
{
    public static QueryStringParser QueryStringParser { get; private set;}
}
```

This is the QueryStringParser class.

```
public class QueryStringParser
{
    public bool HasParam(string parameter)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request[parameter]);
    }
}
```

This is my asp.net web page.

```
if (Url.QueryStringParser.HasParam("Id"))
{ 
    // Do stuff.
}
```

So my question is if it's possible to create something as I've just mentioned above?

Comment: Try it. Does it compile? Does it run? This is an example of a question that you would get an answer to much faster by trying yourself and playing around than asking here.

Comment: Try it.  Did it work?  If not, what went wrong?  THAT is the question you should be asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that the property `QueryStringParser`, to call the method `HasParam`, needs an instance of an object `QueryStringParser` (bad choice of names). This instance is never created by your code, thus the NullReferenceException.
So you need to change a bit of code in the get and set of your property

```
public class Url
{
    private static QueryStringParser _qsp = null;
    public static QueryStringParser QueryStringParser 
    { 
       get
       {
          if(_qsp == null) _qsp = new QueryStringParser();
          return _qsp;
       }
       private set
       { 
           _qsp = value;
       }
    }
}
```

With this change, when you need the property your code will check if it is null and initializes the internal object used to store the instance of QueryStringParser, then returns this instance.

Another possibility to bypass the exception is to made your HasParam method also static and in this case you don't need an instance of the object QueryStringParser.

By the way, while it works, I find extremely confusing to have a property named as a class. I suggest to choose another name for the property  `QueryStringParser`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation ^.^ I'm going to experiment more with these things and read some more in the internet about it to fully understand it all.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is assign it an instance in the static constructor of URL:

```
public class Url
{
     public static Url()
     { 
         QueryStringParser = new QueryStringParser();
     }

     public static QueryStringParser QueryStringParser { get; private set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Url
{
    public static QueryStringParser QueryStringParser { get; private set; }
}
```

This is not right you need to make a instance of the class to access its methods and property. I think it would be a good learning exercise for you to research this and resolve it.